# Updated custom generated files on save

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, msbuild

In a `.xaml` file as soon as I add a new control, I am able to reference it for the `xaml.cs` file because VS is kind enough the generate the C# code for it in a `g.i.cs` file.

For example

In MainWindow.xaml I add

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="Test"/>
</Grid>
```

I am able to access it from MainWindow.xaml.cs like

```
this.Test.Content = "TestButton";
```

Because VS generated MainWindow.g.i.cs in the obj folder which contains

```
internal System.Windows.Controls.Button Test;
```

I have been able to have exactly the same behavior using msbuild for a custom file `.xyz` which is a designer view for a `.cs` file. I've have created a msbuild target that regenerates the `.cs` files **on build and on project load but I'm not able to do the same thing on file save**

Now my questions:

1. How does VS regenerate the `g.i.cs` on save ?
2. Is this a VS feature or an msbuild one ?
3. Can I trigger an incremental build on save?

**Update:**

I've also looked through a WPF `.csproj` and it uses the same `.targets` files as a class library C# project. The only differences I could spot are the `DependentUpon` and the `SubType` item metadata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. How does VS regenerate the g.i.cs on save ?

AFAIK, Visual Studio invoke the XAML compiler `xamlc.exe` to compile the XAML files regenerate the `g.i.cs` on save.

Check this blog [Understanding In and Out of XAML in WPF](https://vishalnayan.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/understanding-in-and-out-of-xaml-in-wpf/):

In the blog, the author said that compilation of XAML happened in 2 steps:

> Step 1. The first step is to compile the XAML files into BAML using the xamlc.exe compiler. For example, **if our project includes a file name Window1.xaml, the compiler will create a temporary file named Window1.baml and place it in the obj\Debug subfolder (in our project folder). At the same time, a partial class is created for our window, using the language of our choice. For example, if we’re using C#, the compiler will create a file named Window1.g.cs in the obj\Debug folder. The g stands for generated.**
>
> Step 2. When the XAML-to-BAML compilation stage is finished, Visual
>   Studio uses the appropriate language compiler to compile our code and
>   the generated partial class files. In the case of a C# application,
>   it’s the csc.exe compiler that handles this task. The compiled code
>   becomes a single assembly Window1.exe) and the BAML for each window is
>   embedded as a separate resource.

.

> 2. Is this a VS feature or an msbuild one?

This should be Visual Studio feature. As I said above, Visual Studio invoke the XAML compiler `xamlc.exe` to compile the `.xaml` files on save. Visual Studio will invoke MSBuild to compile the those file to `.exe`/`.dll` **on build**. Besides, when you on save not build the project, you can open your Task Manager, there is no MSBuild.exe exists, only when you build the project, it will comes up. So this should be Visual Studio feature not MSBuild on save.

> 3. Can I trigger an incremental build on save?

In the Visual Studio, the build system provides support for incremental builds. But if you want trigger an incremental build with your a custom MSBuild file `.xyz`, I am afraid you could not do that, because MSBuild only works on Build not save.

> The [!INCLUDETLA2#tla_wpf] build system provides support for incremental builds. It is fairly intelligent about detecting changes made to markup or code, and it compiles only those artifacts affected by the change. The incremental build mechanism uses the following files

Check the [Building a WPF Application (WPF)](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/framework/wpf/app-development/building-a-wpf-application-wpf.md) for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, the Task Manager and MSBuild part really didn't occur to me. I want to look a bit more into it but If I no solution to it I'll mark yours as the correct one.